# Does Rust has a type equivalent to Scala's Nothing type?

Tags: rust

In Scala we can set unknown types to `Nothing`. In the following code `Remove` and `Expire` sets the type of value to `Nothing`.

Merging the two collections where one collection (`putUpdateRemove`) knows the value type and the other (`removeExpire`) where value type is unknown results in a collection (`combined`) where the type of value is inferred/known by the compiler.

```scala
sealed trait KeyValue[K, +V]
case class Put[K, V](key: K, value: V) extends KeyValue[K, V]
case class Update[K, V](key: K, value: V) extends KeyValue[K, V]
case class Remove[K](key: K) extends KeyValue[K, Nothing] //Nothing value
case class Expire[K](key: K, time: Long) extends KeyValue[K, Nothing] //Nothing value

object Test {
  // a collection where the type of value is known
  val putUpdateRemove: Seq[KeyValue[Int, Int]] = Seq(Put(1, 1), Update(2, 2), Remove(3))
  // a collection where the type of value is unknown
  val removeExpire: Seq[KeyValue[Int, Nothing]] = Seq(Remove(1), Expire(2, System.currentTimeMillis()))
  //merge the two collections infers the type of value. 
  val combined: Seq[KeyValue[Int, Int]] = putUpdateRemove ++ removeExpire
}
```

Is this possible in Rust? I was hoping the [Never](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) type would be it. But the following code errors with `mismatched types expected i32, found !`.

```rust
#![feature(never_type)]

use std::time::SystemTime;

enum KeyValue<K, V> {
    Put { key: K, value: V },
    Update { key: K, value: V },
    Remove { key: K },
    Expire { key: K, time: SystemTime },
}

fn main() {
    let mut put_update_remove: Vec<KeyValue<i32, i32>> =
        vec![KeyValue::Put { key: 1, value: 1 }, KeyValue::Update { key: 2, value: 2 }, KeyValue::Remove { key: 3 }];

    let mut remove_expire: Vec<KeyValue<i32, !>> =
        vec![KeyValue::Remove { key: 1 }, KeyValue::Expire { key: 2, time: SystemTime::now() }];

    put_update_remove.append(&mut remove_expire);
}
```

Comment: The closest would probably be `()` (unit), but no type will allow you to concatenate vectors of `KeyValue<K, U>` and `KeyValue<K, V>`.

Comment: My presumption would be that `Nothing` is simply Scala's bottom type, so you won't have an analogue because of a lack of subtyping (of this sort) in Rust, though in this instance, as the accepted answer suggests, you can simply rely on inference.

Comment: `!` _is_ the equivalent of `Nothing`; but 1) Rust doesn't have an equivalent of covariance (`+` in `sealed trait KeyValue[K, +V]`); 2) `Nothing` doesn't represent "value type is unknown", but "there are no values".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> one … knows the value type and the other … where value type is unknown results in a collection (combined) where the type of value inferred/known by the compiler.

I'm not familiar with Scala, but if you want to have a concrete type inferred by the compiler, then you can request that using the `_` syntax. Your second example will compile with the type written as follows, using `_` and not `!`.

```rust
let mut remove_expire: Vec<KeyValue<i32, _>> = ...
```

This is merely the syntax for a particular case of Rust's type inference, where the type is partially specified rather than completely specified or left out entirely. (It's often useful with `Iterator::collect()`, where you want to specify the type of collection to produce but don't need to specify the item type.)

The `!` type is something entirely different from `_`: it is a type with *no values,* which is used to represent that a function will never return or, in general, that a value can never be computed (the program will follow some other control flow path).

Comment: "The ! type is something entirely different: it is a type with no values, which is used to represent that a function will never return or, in general, that a value can never be computed (the program will follow some other control flow path)." That's what `Nothing` actually is as well.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, you can simply let the compiler infer *all* the types:

```
let mut put_update_remove = vec![
    KeyValue::Put { key: 1, value: 1 },
    KeyValue::Update { key: 2, value: 2 },
    KeyValue::Remove { key: 3 },
];

let mut remove_expire = vec![
    KeyValue::Remove { key: 1 },
    KeyValue::Expire {
        key: 2,
        time: SystemTime::now(),
    },
];

put_update_remove.append(&mut remove_expire);
```

Unlike some other languages, Rust does not require explicit types for all variables. It's common in Rust for the only explicit type annotations in a function to be in the function signature (where they are required).

If you want to specify part of a type and let the compiler infer the rest, the `_` placeholder (as Kevin's answer mentions) is the way to do that.